# Will Heroku dyno automatic restarts kill running processing on my application?

Tags: heroku

I have an application that is hosted on Heroku. The application has a process that is run on the server, that the user has the ability to start and stop. Once the user clicks 'Start', the process is supposed to stay running until the user presses 'Stop'. The functionality of the app should allow that the process can be run for extended periods of times (6 months or so) continuously.

I have deployed my app on a Heroku free dyno. While reading the Heroku documentation, I came across [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) page that states that Heroku Dynos are restarted automatically every 24 hours. Here is the relevant passage:

> Dynos are also restarted (cycled) at least once per day to help maintain the health of applications running on Heroku. Any changes to the local filesystem will be deleted. The cycling happens once every 24 hours (plus up to 216 random minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at the same time). Manual restarts (heroku ps:restart) and releases (deploys or changing config vars) will reset this 24 hour period. Cycling happens for all dynos, including one-off dynos, so dynos will run for a maximum of 24 hours + 216 minutes. If you have multiple dynos, they should cycle at different times based on the random 0 to 216 minutes difference. If you continually make changes to your application without a 24 hour gap, you won’t see cycling at all.

Does this mean that the user process that he/she has started will automatically be stopped when the dyno restarts? If yes, does it automatically resume the user process where it left off?

If not, I will have to find a different hosting solution since the process may need to be run 24x7x365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that the user process that he/she has started will automatically be stopped when the dyno restarts?

Yes it does. As it will when you change config variables, or deploy updates, or add / remove addons.

> If yes, does it automatically resume the user process where it left off?

No it doesn't. Any safe-and-resume behaviour you have to implement in your application. When stopping processes, Heroku will send them a `SIGTERM` signal and give them 30 seconds to safe their work.

> If not, I will have to find a different hosting solution since the process may need to be run 24x7x365.

I doubt that there is any hosting solution that will give you what you want. In a cloud environment restarts are a thing that happens all the time, at least for you updating your application, bugfixes, security fixes. Every hosting provider or platform that provides you with *24x7x365* uptime will also restart and replace your dynos all the time.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that I am the only user of the application. Would a VPS like DigitalOcean be a solution to my problems? If somehow I could access my DO hosted app on the web (while it remains private to the rest of the world) without having to ssh every time, that would be the perfect solution.

Comment: not really. They will not have this 24 hour restart, but they will definitely reboot / restart servers sometimes for updates. Also they won't have all the other advantages of Heroku :)

Comment: Well Digital Ocean doesn't have an automatic restart policy for their droplets like Heroku though so why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @philosopher while they don't do automatic daily restarts I highly doubt That this means 24/7/365 uptime, also I highly doubt you will never need to update your application :)

Comment: Well true, I guess I should rephrase 24/7/365. Its more like 24x7 with some restarts here and there but definitely not a automatic daily restart like with Heroku. I guess for this use-case DO would work with a ssh tunnel socks proxy.

Comment: If this is the case though, what is the correct way to write an application that has in-memory state? I have a server that supports an online game and keeps game state in memory, and when the dyno restarts all games cease to exist and anyone playing has to start a new game. Obviously most online games don't have this drawback - what is the solution? For real-time games like agar.io you can't be saving all the games in a database, the transaction speed would slow the game down dramatically.

Comment: you could keep the in-memory state outside the dyno, for example in redis, if that's fast enough. Or make a "backup" of the in-memory state asynchronously, and fetch it on boot. You can also upload the state to redis on SIGTERM when the dyno shuts down.


With every systen you will have restarts / reboots. 

( in any case, it could also be that for this usecase, Heroku is not the right platform)